# DeprecationWarning rasied in Spyder for every Scipy function used

Tags: python, scipy, spyder, deprecation-warning

I'm coding in Spyder and the code runs, but **every** line that uses sp.___ raises a DeprecationWarning, e.g. `DeprecationWarning: scipy.array is deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 2.0.0, use numpy.array instead`.

Why is Spyder doing this and how do I allow me to use scipy without raising this error? Failing that, what can I do to suppress the error from popping up each time?

The code is like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as op
a=9.3779
x_in=sp.array([.095,.065,.09,.108,.125,.115,.040,.055,.055])
x=(x_in+14)
y_in=sp.array([.2,.6,.5,.4,.1,.3,-0.2,-0.4,0])
y=y_in+45
ax.plot(x_in,y_in,'ro')
plt.show()
```

This raises the error:

`C:\Users\Shiva Pingle\Desktop\python\others\peaks.py:38: DeprecationWarning: scipy.array is deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 2.0.0, use numpy.array instead
  x_in=sp.array([.095,.065,.09,.108,.125,.115,.040,.055,.055])
C:\Users\Shiva Pingle\Desktop\python\others\peaks.py:40: DeprecationWarning: scipy.array is deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 2.0.0, use numpy.array instead
  y_in=sp.array([.2,.6,.5,.4,.1,.3,-0.2,-0.4,0])`

Comment: I don't think the problem in Sypder, could you post the code causing the problem??

Comment: I just got it to ignore the errors by using: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution in the comments will make you ignore all the deprecation warnings. This is not suggested.

You could instead `import numpy as np` and use the `np.array()`.

Corrected code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize as op
import numpy as np    # Added import of numpy

a=9.3779

x_in=np.array([.095,.065,.09,.108,.125,.115,.040,.055,.055]) # Changed sp to np
x=(x_in+14)

y_in=np.array([.2,.6,.5,.4,.1,.3,-0.2,-0.4,0]) # Changed sp to np
y=y_in+45

plt.plot(x_in,y_in,'ro') # Also changed the ax to plt
plt.show()
```

Comment: But what's the reason why Spyder is throwing up an error when I use Scipy functions. You're effectively saying to not use the Scipy library.

Comment: Spyder only throws the warning for the `sp.array` function. The scipy functions can take as an argument numpy arrays (ndarray). For example the `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) takes as arguments numpy arrays.

Comment: Is there another SciPy  function that throws a DeprecationWarning after you changed `sp.array` to `np.array`?

Comment: This the correct answer (+1). It has nothing to do with spyder, it's just a one change of the scipy library itself.

Comment: For what it‘s worth, I’ve received similar warning for `sp.arange` and `sp.cumsum`. Replacing them with `np` equivalents also solved the warning.  It’s the same for all `numpy` functions called directly from `scipy` since `scipy-1.4.0` as documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.4.0.html#deprecated-features), with a special treatment to `sp.fft`